# how do i stop the looping output of the else statement until the value is found in a text file?

Tags: python

The code below is a summer project that i have been working on:

```
from time import sleep

def valrep(x,change): #function goes through a file and replaces specific values
    with open('users.txt', 'r') as file :
        filedata = file.read()
    for aline in open("users.txt","r").readlines():
        word = aline.split()
        if (word[0] == username) and (word[1] == user_password):
            aline2 = aline.replace(word[x], change)
            filedata = filedata.replace(aline,aline2)
    with open('users.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
        print("SUCCESS")

loop = False
while loop == False:
    username = input("ENTER A VALID USERNAME>>> ")#splits the input into two seperate variables
    user_password = input("ENTER A VALID 4 DIGIT PIN>>> ")
    valnums = '1234567890' #gives a set of valid characters (used later in the program)
    with open("users.txt","r") as user_file:
        for aline in user_file.readlines():
            vals = aline.split()
            if (vals[0] == username) and (vals[1] == user_password):#goes through the text file looking for the valid username and password
                loop2 = False
                while loop2 == False:
                    sleep(3.0) #delays the time for menu to appear
                    print("\n"*300,"="*30,"\n\n\nWELCOME TO HAYDON BANK, {} \n\n\n".format(username),"="*30,"\n  WHICH SERVICE DO YOU REQUIRE?\n","="*30,"\n\n\n    Option 1: View Balance\n\n    Option 2: Withdrawal\n\n    Option 3: Change PIN\n\n\n","="*30,"\n")#this is the menu
                    balance = vals[2] #sets respective part of the file as the balance variable
                    print("\n"*6)
                    option = input("INPUT OPTION PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT>>> ")
                    if option == '1':
                        print("£",balance)
                        sleep(2.0)
                    elif option == '2':
                        withdrawal = input("SELECT AMOUNT TO WITHDRAW:\n £10\n £20\n £50\n £100\n OR INPUT AN AMOUNT THAT IS DIVISIBLE BY 10\n\n\nINPUT AMOUNT>>> £")
                        if withdrawal%10 == 0:
                            print("You selected:£",withdrawal)
                            newbalance = float(balance) - float(withdrawal)#sets the newbalance variable
                            valrep(2,str(newbalance))
                            print("New Balance:£",newbalance)
                            sleep(2.0)
                    elif option == '3':
                        loop3 = True
                        while loop3 == True:
                            old_pass, new_pass = input("input old PIN and new PIN: ").split(" ")
                            if len(new_pass) != 4: #checks if new_pass is 4 characters long
                                print("INCORRECT LENGTH")
                            elif False in [c in valnums for c in new_pass]: #loops through valnums and compares the variable new_pass to have valid characters   
                                print("INVALID CHARACTERS")
                            elif old_pass == user_password: #checks if old_pass is equal to user_password
                                valrep(1,new_pass)
                                print("New PIN: ",new_pass)
                                loop3 = False
                                sleep(2.0)
                    elif option.lower() == 'q':
                        loop2 = True
                        print("Bye", username)
                        sleep(5.0)
                    else:
                        print("INVALID INPUT")
            else:
                print("INVALID INPUT")
                break
```

users.txt file:

```
user0001 1234 123.45
user0002 1234 123.45
user0003 1234 123.45
...
user9999 1234 123.45
```

the problem is that when i input values that are closer to line 9999 in the text file in username or user_password variables, it gives me this output:

```
"INVALID INPUT"
"INVALID INPUT"
"INVALID INPUT"
...
```

until the code has found the values in the text file.

but i want the output to be like this:

```
ENTER A VALID USERNAME>>> user9999
ENTER A VALID 4 DIGIT PIN>>> 1234

 ============================== 


WELCOME TO HAYDON BANK, user0001 


 ============================== 
  WHICH SERVICE DO YOU REQUIRE?
 ============================== 


    Option 1: View Balance

    Option 2: Withdrawal

    Option 3: Change PIN


 ============================== 





INPUT OPTION PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT>>>
```

how do i do this?

note: i am not a REAL programmer, im just a kid that knows most of the basics of python coding and **no other type of coding**

Comment: Re: "how to stop the output until..." would indicate that it never started; please clarify your question.

Comment: im not really sure how to word this question without breaking the 150 character mark

Comment: Maybe you mean "how to stop the output when it reaches the value..."?

Comment: no, when the code searches for the value, as it loops through the file, it outputs "INCORRECT INPUT" for everything that isnt the value im looking for

Comment: I guess it's still not clear; maybe provide an example of your `users.txt` input file.

Comment: file = open("users.txt","w+")
for i in range(1,10000):
    x = '{0:04}'.format(i)
    print("user{} 1234 123.45".format(x))
    file.write("user{} 1234 123.45".format(x))

Comment: @l'L'l run that in python

Comment: that should give you the entire contents of the users.txt file

Comment: That lower case "L" in the middle "SElECT" hurts.

Comment: Please read "[ask]", then [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, including inputs (hard-coded strings would be fine), outputs, and what behavior you expected instead.  The attempt to isolate an MCVE might locate the bug you're trying to solve.  (Also, breaking that huge indented mass into separate functions can only make your life easier.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you expect is not consistent with what you code.

```
for aline in user_file.readlines():
    vals = aline.split()
    if (vals[0] == username) and (vals[1] == user_password):
        #...
    else:
        print("INVALID INPUT")
        break
```

Since you match from the first line, mismatch will occur until you find a match given username="user9999". And everytime a mismatch occur an "invalid input" will be print.

A quick way to fix this is using "for...else...". See [a reference of `for ... else ..`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) ( A `break` is needed to let the `else` know we get what we searched.)

```
for aline in user_file.readlines():
    vals = aline.split()
    if (vals[0] == username) and (vals[1] == user_password):
        #Process...
        break #let the "else" in next line knowing "we have found"
else:
    print("INVALID INPUT")
    break
```

In the above code, the `else` statement is executed only no match found. Hope this is what you want.

#### -----------------------------------------

Runable code changed based on what you posted.

```
from time import sleep
def valrep(x,change): #function goes through a file and replaces specific values
    with open('users.txt', 'r') as file :
        filedata = file.read()
    for aline in open("users.txt","r").readlines():
        word = aline.split()
        if (word[0] == username) and (word[1] == user_password):
            aline2 = aline.replace(word[x], change)
            filedata = filedata.replace(aline,aline2)
    with open('users.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
        print("SUCCESS")

loop = False
while loop == False:
    username = input("ENTER A VALID USERNAME>>> ")#splits the input into two seperate variables
    user_password = input("ENTER A VALID 4 DIGIT PIN>>> ")
    valnums = '1234567890' #gives a set of valid characters (used later in the program)
    with open("users.txt","r") as user_file:
        for aline in user_file.readlines():
            vals = aline.split()
            if (vals[0] == username) and (vals[1] == user_password):#goes through the text file looking for the valid username and password
                loop2 = False
                while loop2 == False:
                    sleep(3.0) #delays the time for menu to appear
                    print("\n"*3,"="*30,"\n\n\nWELCOME TO HAYDON BANK, {} \n\n\n".format(username),"="*30,"\n  WHICH SERVICE DO YOU REQUIRE?\n","="*30,"\n\n\n    Option 1: View Balance\n\n    Option 2: Withdrawal\n\n    Option 3: Change PIN\n\n\n","="*30,"\n")#this is the menu
                    balance = vals[2] #sets respective part of the file as the balance variable
                    print("\n"*6)
                    option = input("INPUT OPTION PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT>>> ")
                    if option == '1':
                        print("£",balance)
                        sleep(2.0)
                    elif option == '2':
                        withdrawal = input("SElECT AMOUNT TO WITHDRAW:\n £10\n £20\n £50\n £100\n OR INPUT AN AMOUNT THAT IS DIVISIBLE BY 10\n\n\nINPUT AMOUNT>>> £")
                        if withdrawal%10 == 0:
                            print("You selected:£",withdrawal)
                            newbalance = float(balance) - float(withdrawal)#sets the newbalance variable
                            valrep(2,str(newbalance))
                            print("New Balance:£",newbalance)
                            sleep(2.0)
                    elif option == '3':
                        loop3 = True
                        while loop3 == True:
                            old_pass, new_pass = input("input old PIN and new PIN: ").split(" ")
                            if len(new_pass) != 4: #checks if new_pass is 4 characters long
                                print("INCORRECT LENGTH")
                            elif False in [c in valnums for c in new_pass]: #loops through valnums and compares the variable new_pass to have valid characters
                                print("INVALID CHARACTERS")
                            elif old_pass == user_password: #checks if old_pass is equal to user_password
                                valrep(1,new_pass)
                                print("New PIN: ",new_pass)
                                loop3 = False
                                sleep(2.0)
                    elif option.lower() == 'q':
                        loop2 = True
                        print("Bye", username)
                        sleep(5.0)
                    else:
                        print("INVALID INPUT")
                break  # this break is needed to let the "else" in next line knowing "we have found what we want"
        else:
            print("INVALID INPUT!!")
            continue #comment this if you allow multi-user or re-login
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say 'change the level of "else"'?

Comment: Notice the difference between the above two code snippets. A "for .. else" structure is helpful in the scenario when searching for something then do something else if no match found. I may should not use the word "change the level". But the idea is to use "for..else.."

Comment: oh so keep the for...else... on the same indentation?

Comment: instead of break use "continue" so it doesn't end the code